# Call Two Function OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is piece of my working code

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel1" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this alert?','Confirm');" onClick="lnkDelete1_Click" CssClass="del_lnk" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID").ToString()%>' />
```

Now I Want to call another function **bindBlockUI();** which block UI on client click so user may not click once again.

Now its generating alert with two button **No** and **Confirm**, When i click on **No** nothings happen but on confirm some event called.

I want to block UI as soon as User click on confirm from alert box.

How to achieve this.

Comment: So basically you want to call `bindBlockUI` right after `confirm`?

Comment: yes exactly i want to do this

Comment: there is tons of blockui jquery plugin an example would be http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: or you can write you own one by providing a absolute div overlay when clicking the button

Comment: I already check that and I am using bindBlockUI() in my whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have done something like this and its working perfectly. It also not firing main function on cancellation from alert box. Although Thanks for answer beacause yours answers leads me to this answer

```
function clearItem() 
{ 
    var result = confirm('Delete this alert?', 'Confirm'); 
    if (result) { 
        bindBlockUI(); 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first define a common function:

```
function myFunction(){
var o=confirm('Delete this alert?','Confirm');
bindBlockUI();
return o;
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel1" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return myFunction();" onClick="lnkDelete1_Click" CssClass="del_lnk" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID").ToString()%>' />
```

Comment: now even after cancellation from alert box my main event firing

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite easier to read if you define a function.

```
function onClientClick() {
    var result = confirm('Delete this alert?','Confirm');
    bindBlockUI();
    return result;
}
```

Then: `OnClientClick="return onClientClick();"`

But you should really avoid using inline handlers in favor of `addEventListener`.

```
document.getElementById('lnkDel1').addEventListener('click', onClientClick);
```

However if you use `addEventListener` you must change the code slightly to prevent the default event from fireing.

```
function onClientClick(e) {
    if (!confirm('Delete this alert?','Confirm')) e.preventDefault();
    bindBlockUI();
}
```

Comment: mate i answered it first

Comment: I will but now even after cancellation from alert box my main event firing

Comment: @user3049290 Sorry, I added more precisions.

Comment: function clearItem() {
            var result = confirm('Delete this alert?', 'Confirm');
            if (result) {
                bindBlockUI();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }